# C Not sure what to free properly

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc

I have a school homework for a linked list, this is all my functions and I need to finish the free function but I'm quite new to C so not really sure what exactly do I have to free

here is my code:

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee * m_Next;
    struct TEmployee * m_Bak;
    char * m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;

#endif /* __PROGTEST__ */

TEMPLOYEE * newEmployee(const char * name, TEMPLOYEE * next)
{
    TEMPLOYEE* head = NULL;
    head = (TEMPLOYEE *)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    head -> m_Name = strdup(name);
    head -> m_Next = next;
    head -> m_Bak = NULL;

    return head;
}

int getEmpPos(TEMPLOYEE *list, TEMPLOYEE *el){
    int pos = 0;
    TEMPLOYEE *listPos = list;

    while(listPos != NULL){
        if(listPos == el)
            return pos;

        listPos = listPos->m_Next;
        pos++;
    }

    return -1;
}

TEMPLOYEE* getEmpAtPos(TEMPLOYEE* list, int pos)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *toReturn = list;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        toReturn = toReturn->m_Next;
    }

    return toReturn;
}

TEMPLOYEE * cloneList(TEMPLOYEE * src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE* current = src;
    TEMPLOYEE* newList = NULL;
    TEMPLOYEE* tail = NULL;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(newList==NULL)
        {
            newList = (TEMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
            newList -> m_Name = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(current -> m_Name));
            strcpy(newList -> m_Name, current -> m_Name);
            newList -> m_Next = NULL;
            newList -> m_Bak = NULL;
            tail = newList;
        }
        else
        {
            tail -> m_Next = (TEMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
            tail = tail -> m_Next;
            tail -> m_Name = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(current -> m_Name));
            strcpy(tail -> m_Name, current -> m_Name);
            tail -> m_Next = NULL;
        }
        current = current -> m_Next;
    }

    // Clone backups
    current = src;
    tail = newList;

    while(current != NULL){
        if(current -> m_Bak)
        {
            tail -> m_Bak = getEmpAtPos(newList, getEmpPos(src, current->m_Bak));
        }
        else
        {
            tail -> m_Bak = NULL;
        }

        tail = tail -> m_Next;
        current = current -> m_Next;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

and this is my free function but this way it only frees some things but not others

```
void freeList(TEMPLOYEE * src)
{

TEMPLOYEE* tmp;

    while(src != NULL)
    {
        tmp = src;
        src = src -> m_Next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and (the non-.standard) `strdup` functions all allocate memory that need to be free'd with `free`. Should be documented quite well.

Comment: Where/when do I free it? For example, how do I free the head in `head = (TEMPLOYEE *)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));` ?

Comment: Isn't that what `freeList` is supposed to do?

Comment: Every call to `malloc` should be `free`d. `freeList` appears to (presumably) free all the `TEMPLOYEE` after the node; try `freeList` of the head of every list?

Answer (score 2):

There are only two functions that allocate memory that needs to be freed.

The `newEmployee` function creates a string with [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) that must be freed, as well as the `TEMPLOYEE` object itself.

The other function that allocates memory is `cloneList`, however it only clones a list. If we can first figure out how to properly free one list, we only need to make sure we free all cloned lists as well to ensure we free memory allocated in `cloneList`.

To properly free the list, we need to free each `TEMPLOYEE` object and the `m_Name` that it holds. Your free list function can be modified like so:

```
void freeList(TEMPLOYEE * src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *next = src;
    while (next != NULL) {
        TEMPLOYEE *prev = next;
        next = prev->m_Next;
        free(prev->m_Name);
        free(prev);
    }
}
```

As long as you call this on all lists, including those created by `cloneList`, all memory should be freed.